# is this interface correct and use of unique_ptr correct?

Tags: c++, comparative-review, c++14

I present here a piece of code taken from a book about mastering Qt5.

it's the use of unique_ptr in the way shown below which I found to be suspicious and unusual(IMO).

```
class AlbumDao
{
public:
    AlbumDao(QSqlDatabase& database);
    void init() const;

    void addAlbum(Album& album) const;
    void updateAlbum(const Album& album) const;
    void removeAlbum(int id) const;
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Album>>> albums() const;

private:
    QSqlDatabase& mDatabase;
};
```

here is the implementation of albums() where we allocate dynamic memory even for std::vector.

```
unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<Album>>> AlbumDao::albums() const
{
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM albums", mDatabase);
    query.exec();
    unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<Album>>> list(new vector<unique_ptr<Album>>());
    while(query.next()) {
        unique_ptr<Album> album(new Album());
        album->setId(query.value("id").toInt());
        album->setName(query.value("name").toString());
        list->push_back(move(album));
    }
    return list;
}

//Album is just a Data holder class.
```

so, my question are:

- is the use of unique_ptr in this way is correct?
- unique_ptr is not copyable, so does the compiler move it automaticly?(without an explicit std::move)
- why allocation of dynamic memory for std::vector?

so in short, I am asking to review this code and decide whether is it correct to use unique_ptr in code like so.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to wrap the `std::vector` into a `std::unique_ptr`. Is there any specific reason why you did this? `std::vector` allocates it's elements in the dynamic storage anyways.

Comment: no(IMO), that's why I am asking, and it's not my code, it's the code of the book.

Comment: Questions must involve real code that you own or maintain. Pseudocode, hypothetical code, or stub code should be replaced by a concrete implementation. Questions seeking an explanation of someone else's code are also off-topic.

Comment: it's, not pseudo code, if you ask me to add all the code I will do it.

Comment: You admitted the code is not your own. That's a problem.

Comment: yes, true, why it will pose a problem? How does it affect reviewing and seeing if this code is a clean code, conform to cpp core guide line, respect rules ?

Comment: @chedynajjar _"why will it pose a problem"_ Because _"Questions must involve real code that you own or maintain. Pseudocode, hypothetical code, or stub code should be replaced by a concrete implementation. **Questions seeking an explanation of someone else's code are also off-topic**."_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I don't see why posting somebody else's code to learn from it is a problem when the question is "is this style/pattern/way of writing code is a correct/conform to C++ norm ".

Comment: @chedynajjar Here's the relevant link: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3654

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, if you insist, I am using this pattern in my current code, I guess I will edit the post, is it ok?

Comment: @t3chb0t, okay, thx, good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the use of unique_ptr in this way correct?

Yes, it's correct, but it's not idiomatic. There are two reasons I can think of to use `unique_ptr<Album>` instead of `Album` directly:

- If `Album` is not default-constructible, not copyable, or not moveable — that is, if `Album` is not a value-semantic and/or regular type — then you may find you can't manipulate `Album`s in all the ways you want to. A good example of this use-case is `std::mutex`: you can't meaningfully create a `std::vector<std::mutex>`, but you could create a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>>`.
- As a special case of "not copyable": if `Album` is a polymorphic class, then you might need to heap-allocate the individual `Album`s. You can't create a heterogeneous "vector" in C++, but you *can* create a `vector<Base*>` where each `Base*` points to an instance of a different derived class.

However, neither of these use-cases applies to the code you posted, so all I can think is that the programmer was cargo-culting some code from an environment in which most classes he dealt with were polymorphic.

(Notice that `Album` does not have a virtual destructor, so it can't meaningfully be polymorphic.)

---

> unique_ptr is not copyable, so does the compiler move it automaticly?(without an explicit std::move)

Yes, in most cases. For example, the construct `return foo;` (when `foo` is a parameter or local variable) automatically [treats `foo` as if it were an rvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return). Idiomatic C++ code contains very few explicit `std::move`s, especially at the business-logic level. (If you're implementing hardcore template-metaprogramming libraries, it's a different story.)

---

> Why allocation of dynamic memory for std::vector?

Again, it smells to me like the author was cargo-culting the practice from some codebase where "every object is heap-allocated" was just a rule of thumb. Perhaps their codebase was automatically translated from Java or C# (two languages where that rule of thumb is actually baked into the language semantics: in many OO languages, you simply *cannot* create class instances that aren't heap-allocated).

This is *not* good C++ practice, and you should not copy it.

---

Lastly, note that this code:

```
unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<Album>>> list(new vector<unique_ptr<Album>>());
```

is particularly bad C++03-style C++11. In idiomatic C++14, it would be

```
auto list = std::make_unique<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Album>>>();
```

and of course without all the heap-allocation one would hope the entire function could be just

```
std::vector<Album> result;
while (query.next()) {
    result.emplace_back(  // assuming Album has the appropriate constructor
        query.value("id").toInt(),
        query.value("name").toString()
    );
}
return result;
```